# Why is it neccessary to include the file.h file into the file.c in multiple compilation units project

Tags: c

Here is the scenario:

**file.h**

```
#ifndef _FILE_
#define _FILE_
void foo(void);
#endif
```

**file.c**

```
#include "file.h"   //why is this line necessary?
void foo(void)
{
   do something here...    
}
```

Comment: Why indeed? What happens when you omit that line?

Comment: Usual warning : underscore-capital names are reserved in the global namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done to catch inconsistencies between the function declaration in the header file and the function definition in the .c file. For example, the following will generate an error message from the compiler

**file.h**

```
#ifndef _FILE_
#define _FILE_
void foo(void);
#endif
```

**file.c**

```
#include "file.h"   //This line is for error checking

void foo( int someArgThatWasntInTheDeclaration )
{
   do something here...    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The implementation file `file.c` may require forward declarations of functions and other variables from the header file `file.h`.

The linker and pre-processor need that information to construct the virtual function mappings to produce the executable output.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario it is not necessary but in a slighly more compilcated scenario it is:

**file.h**

```
#ifndef _FILE_
#define _FILE_

struct mystruct
{
   ...
};

void foo(struct mystruc *bar);

#endif
```

**file.c**

```
#include "file.h"   //why is this line necessary?

void foo(struct mystruct *bar)
{
   do something here...    
}
```

**file2.c**

```
#include "file.h"   //Q: why is this line necessary?
                    //A: because it defines struct mystruct

...
struct mystruct mystructvariable;
...
foo(&mystructvariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your complete program is only a single C source file, indeed, you do not require a separate header file and the corresponding #include directive.

If, however, as is most common, there are *several* C source files calling `foo`, you want to make sure they all see the same `foo` prototype. That's why placing prototypes in a common header is the best practice.

On a more advanced description level, a header declares an **interface**, i.e. the set of functions, types and macros needed to make use of a service. A C source provides an **implementation**. Separating interface and implementation is a powerful programming paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

The [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) is mostly doing *textual* transformations. In particular, it does not know much about the syntax of C (because it does not deal with [abstract syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) -or ASTs- like some [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) language implementations do).

You are not *required* to `#include "file.h"` in every [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) `file1.c`, `file2.c` etc... that you are coding. You could instead copy & paste some common code chunks, but this would be error-prone if done manually. So *conventionally* people *prefer* to `#include "file.h"` at start of each `file1.c`, `file2.c` etc. Also, builder tools like [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) may be able to manage such dependencies.

If your C code is generated by some software tool, that generator tool could emit several times the same declarations, and won't need to emit any `#include "file.h"`

Notice that most [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) do not know about type information of global symbols (like function names). It could be possible to erroneously link some [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) `foo3.o` (e.g. in [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format on Linux) defining a `int foo (void)` function with another object file `foo4.o` expecting an `extern void foo(char*)` function, but the resulting [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable)  program would exhibit some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Then you are more likely to avoid such typing errors by `#include`-ing a common header declaring `foo` in every (or most) `file*.c` translation units.